# Create list from list with condition using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sum

I have a list called `[7,1,2,2,3,1,2,3,3]`. So we have to create another list with elements like if element in original is one time then simply append, if elements multiple times and in consecutive then sum up and add into new list. Output for above list should be `[7,1,4,3,1,2,6]`

any help is much appreciable.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another case [for `itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), it's great at merging runs of identical values:

```
from itertools import groupby

mylist = [7,1,2,2,3,1,2,3,3]

collapsedlist = [sum(grp) for _, grp in groupby(mylist)]

print(collapsedlist)
```

which outputs:

```
[7, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6]
```

It's summing each run of identical numbers (including "runs" of a single value, so no special handling needed for the non-duplicate case), replacing the run with the sum.

Comment: Thanks for solution. Could you please help me to get this using some logic(not inbuilt function). I did something. `def test(n):
  sumr =0
  listq=[]
  for x ,y in enumerate(n):
    print (x,y)
    if n[x] == n[x+1]:
      sumr+= n[x]
      continue
    else:
      sumr += n[x]
    
    listq.append(sumr)
    sumr = 0
  print (listq)
    
test([2,6,7,7,8,8,7])`